# Adding a running subtotal to a created food menu

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a program that adds up the orders of a fast food menu. I need to add a running subtotal after I have made an order. As I am a python novice, I am not quite sure what to do. I also need to make sure my order dictionary is modified, but am unsure how to do so.

I thought about making a loop with a range to keep the total but I do not want a range as I want the program to be able to take as many orders as possible.

```
# menu and order options
menu = {"burger":5.00, "fries":3.50, "drink":1.00}
order = {"burger":0, "fries":0, "drink":0}

bcount = 0
fcount = 0
dcount = 0

while True:
    print("Please make a selection:")
    print("1. Burger = $5.00")
    print("2. Fries  = $3.50")
    print("3. Drink  = $1.00")
    print("4. Quit")

    choice = int(input('Please order: '))

    if choice == 1:
        amount = int(input("Enter number of Burgers: "))
        bcount += amount
    elif choice == 2:
        amount = int(input("Enter number of Fries: "))
        fcount += amount
    elif choice == 3:
        amount = int(input("Enter number of Drinks: "))
        dcount += amount
    elif choice == 4:
        sub = (bcount * 5.00) + (fcount * 3.50) + (dcount * 1.00)
        tax = sub * 0.075
        total = sub + tax

        print('Number of Burgers: {0}'.format(bcount))
        print('Number of Fries: {0}'.format(fcount))
        print('Number of Drinks: {0}'.format(dcount))
        print('Subtotal: {:0.2f}'.format(sub))
        print('Tax: {:0.2f}'.format(tax))
        print('Total: {:0.2f}'.format(total))
        break
```

The expected result is after each order, the program would give me a running subtotal.

Example: after an order of a burger is entered would look like:
Your subtotal is: $5.00

Then the next order is an order of fries and a drink
Your subtotal is: $9.50 (adding the burger from the previous order)

Comment: You don’t need to break actually because you can have as many order as you want!!! You need to just re assign bcount fcount and dcount to zero if choice is 4 that will mimic as the new order

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add a variable called subtotal in the beginning called **subtotal**. Attached one example for the burger that can be applied to the rest. I agree with previous commenter regarding reset of variables instead of **break**.

```
subtotal=0
bcount = 0
fcount = 0
dcount = 0

if choice == 1:
    amount = int(input("Enter number of Burgers: "))
    bcount += amount
    subtotal+=(amount*5)
    print("Your total is: ",subtotal)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume, for option 1 - 3, you need to show the subtotal and for option 4 you need to show the full report.

I have updated the code as following:

- added `calculate_sub_total` method.
- displayed subtotal for option 1-3.
- separated the `if-elif-else` to two partitions.
- Used the `menu` dictionary to fetch prices for items both in sub total calculation and in displaying the menu.
- Used the `order` dictionary to keep track of the number of items as intended. Removed `bcount`, `dcount`, `fcount` variables as they are not needed anymore.

Updated code:

```
# menu and order options
menu = {"burger":5.00, "fries":3.50, "drink":1.00}
order = {"burger":0, "fries":0, "drink":0}

def calculate_sub_total():
    return (order["burger"] * menu["burger"]) + \
           (order["fries"] * menu["fries"]) + \
           (order["drink"] * menu["drink"])

while True:
    print("Please make a selection:")
    print("1. Burger = ${}".format(menu["burger"]))
    print("2. Fries  = ${}".format(menu["fries"]))
    print("3. Drink  = ${}".format(menu["drink"]))
    print("4. Quit")

    choice = int(input('Please order: '))
    show_subtotal = False
    if choice == 1:
        amount = int(input("Enter number of Burgers: "))
        order["burger"] += amount
        show_subtotal = True
    elif choice == 2:
        amount = int(input("Enter number of Fries: "))
        order["fries"] += amount
        show_subtotal = True
    elif choice == 3:
        amount = int(input("Enter number of Drinks: "))
        order["drink"] += amount
        show_subtotal = True
    sub = calculate_sub_total()
    if show_subtotal:        
        print('Subtotal: {:0.2f}'.format(sub))
    if choice == 4:        
        tax = sub * 0.075
        total = sub + tax
        print('Number of Burgers: {0}'.format(order["burger"]))
        print('Number of Fries: {0}'.format(order["fries"]))
        print('Number of Drinks: {0}'.format(order["drink"]))
        print('Subtotal: {:0.2f}'.format(sub))
        print('Tax: {:0.2f}'.format(tax))
        print('Total: {:0.2f}'.format(total))
        break
```

Output:

[image: order_output]